# react native FlatList Default scroll to the bottom

Tags: javascript, react-native

I wanted to automatically scroll to the end after the data loading was completed, because I did the chat application.

But I'm not satisfied with the current scheme.

```js
  componentDidMount(){
    setTimeout(()=>this._scrollView.scrollToEnd({ animated: false }), 200)
  }
```

This way will cause the content to flash when the page is rendered, because it is 200 milliseconds.

How do you get a callback after the FlatList component has finished loading the data?

Comment: You have to use initialScrollIndex  with getItemLayout. Without getItemLayout, your list can’t know how long it will be until you get to the last row. I suggest u to use inverted method such as using react-native-invertible-scroll-view component.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

The application of chat is complicated, message length, and possible pictures or files. The height of each message can't be obtained. Maybe getItemLayout is not suitable for my project. Inverted looks good. I'm trying. The problem is that the space on the view is blank when the number of messages is small.

Comment: In react-native .. gifted-chat - https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat is a quite good repo for chat application. There are many contributors there. I have check the app that they use react-native-invertible-scroll-view as one of components. Maybe u may refer to on how they develop the chat app.